# Xcode 4.0.2 / iOS SDK 4.3

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

What is the minimum platform/firmware versions for iPhone/iPad?
Particularly interested in iPhone 3GS w/ 4.1 and iPad1 3.2.2
Also want to know if I can produce binaries for 3.1.3 version on iPhone or lower for target device AND for simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can produce binaries for 3.1.3, but cant submit those to the AppStore, since the minimal requirement is 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article : http://www.marco.org/2011/03/24/ios-device-and-os-version-stats-from-instapaper-3-0

Basically, don't bother with anything under 4.x :)